# Make an Android app keep its spot on the home screen on uninstall/reinstall

Tags: installation, home-screen-shortcuts, development

When developing Android apps, I will often end up reinstalling the app I'm working on (deliberately after uninstalling it, or when the build signatures are different).

It's bothersome to always put this app back on the home screen where I want it. And if I don't, I either have to type its name in the app directory (which can take a few letters depending on how similar its name is to other apps) or scroll to find it.

Has anyone found a way to have an app find it's previous spot on a reinstall, or something that would make finding it easier ?

I'm familiar with Tasker and Llama, but couldn't find such options.

Comment: Why are you using different signatures? Anyway if you are installing new apps e.g. via adb I would also use adb to start the app. In the end you could have different shortcuts on your PCs desktop to start your app. No need to do that on Android side.

Comment: I have two build types: debug and release. The release type is signed while the debug isn't. So when I change build variant, it requires me to uninstall the previous version to install the new one.
I didn't think of using the command line or shortcuts, I will try that, good idea !

Comment: You can change the package name of the debug build, then there will be no signature conflict anymore: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the_application_id_for_build_variants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite what you asked for, but you could put a Tasker shortcut on the home screen, and have that task just open the app. You could also have that task try different package names in order to support both your debug and release versions.

Comment: That indeed did the trick ! Had to buy Tasker AutoLaunch (~1€) but well worth it, thanks !

Comment: I've done similar, wrote a small helper app that just serves to send various intents to open other apps.